# A question about interpreting a Set Notation that describes Petri-Net properties

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I have a set notation from a particular paper about Petri-Nets,  that I have read.

$$\mathbf{1}_F( (p,\rho(e)) ) = |\rho^{-1} (p) ∩ ● e|$$

Where $F \subseteq (P \times T) \cup (T \times P)$ and $p \in P$

In general terms, what is $\mathbf{1}_F$?

Comment: I commonly see it (without boldface) as the identity morphism (in category theory), but for this context, it looks like a custom notation at least to me. Have you looked at the "notations" section?

Comment: After carefully reading the paper, I notice that $1_F$ refers to a characteristic function. While it is not a custom notation, this notation is quite uncommon in my opinion. I'm not sure though if identity morphism is a characteristic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed it: this is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function):
$$\mathbf{1}_F(x) = \begin{cases} 1\ ,\ x\in F\\ 0\ ,\ x\notin F \end{cases}$$

It looks like this is a common notation; I am a bit more familiar with another notation $\chi_F$.